# How can I calculate a column by different values and sum it at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

**Situation:**
We have tableA with columns: Date, UniqueID, ClientID, Value

**Requirements:**
Pull out data from TableA for:

A1) **Year today** (without using explicit dates)

B) Sum the Commission and CommissionFee per ClientID:

2. Calculate **CommissionFee** for its Value by multiply by 5%
3. Charging method:

If the Value is <$100 then count times the Value is <100 and multiply **Commission** by $10

If the Value is >=$100 and <$200 then count times the Value is >=$100 and <$200 and multiply **Commission** by $20

Else the value is >=$200 then count time the Value is >=$200 and multiply **Commission** by $30

**Expected outcome:**

```
ClientID                  SumOfCommissionAndCommissionFee
100100                          $155
100101                          $255
100102                           $50
100103                          $200
100104                          $50000
```

Comment: Expected result, but no sample data?!? We need both, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I have access to MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

So I created a table on https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html

```
create table table_test ( UniqueID integer,ClientID integer, Value integer);
    insert into table_test (UniqueID,ClientID, Value) values (1,1, 100);
    insert into table_test (UniqueID,ClientID, Value) values (2,1, 200);
    insert into table_test (UniqueID,ClientID, Value) values (3,2, 100);
    insert into table_test (UniqueID,ClientID, Value) values (4,3, 100);
    insert into table_test (UniqueID,ClientID, Value) values (5,3, 200);
    insert into table_test (UniqueID,ClientID, Value) values (6,3, 300);
    select * from table_test;
```

the table:

```
uniqueid clientid value

1         1        100
2         1        200
3         2        100
4         3        100
5         3        200
6         3        300
```

Than on the same platform run the query:

```
select (count(*) filter(where value<100)*10)+
(count(*) filter(where value>100 and value<200)*20)+
(count(*) filter(where value>=200)*30) as Commission, 
clientid from table_test 
group by clientid;
```

| commission | ClienId |
| --- | --- |
| 60 | 3 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 30 | 1 |

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I noticed it didn't include A1) and the B1). Also, I run it on sql checker websites and it comes up as wrong.

Comment: I run it on my Postgress and it runs great. not sure what is A1 and B1. Can you share what error you get?

Comment: Hi Yuval, thank you for your help. If you look the requirements the A1 is about Year to day without using explicit dates and the B1) is part of the formula you built. So, on the top of it I must ad “+value*0.05)”

Comment: Hey I updated the answer , Hope it makes more sense

Comment: Hi Yuval, what do you think of another way here: CASE WHEN value < 100 THEN CAST(COUNT(value * 10)) WHEN value >= 100 AND < 200 THEN CAST(COUNT(value * 20)) 
ELSE CAST(COUNT(value * 30)) END AS Commission

Comment: I prefer the filter way, it makes more sense for me, and it should be faster.